# Remove a line from listview by TAG ID

Tags: c#

How can I remove a line from the listview using the tag id of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [`ListViewItem.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.remove.aspx) method on the `ListViewItem` you're wanting to remove.

> This method is similar in function to the Remove method of the ListView.ListViewItemCollection in the ListView control that contains the item. You can use the Remove method to remove an item from its ListView control. This feature can be useful if you want to move the item to a different ListView control or need to remove the item based on a request from the user to remove the item from within your application.

For example, you could cycle through all of the `ListViewItems` in your `ListView`, look at the `Tag`, and `Remove` the item you want to remove:

```
// Create the ListView and ListViewItem.
ListView myList = new ListView();
ListViewItem myItem = new ListViewItem { Tag = "MyTag", Text = "My ListViewItem" };
myList.Items.Add(item);

// Look for the ListViewItem with a Tag of "MyTag" and remove it.
foreach (ListViewItem item in myList.Items) {
    if (String.CompareOrdinal(item.Tag as string, "MyTag") == 0) {
        i.Remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

This example exits after removing the first matching item. If there are multiple matching `ListViewItems` that need to be removed, you'd need to make a collection of those and then remove them after that.

Answer (score 1):

here's a quick function i did.  it makes use of linq.  `myTag` can be any object.

```
        string myTag = "aaa";

        List<ListViewItem> lst = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(i => i.Tag == myTag).ToList();
        if (lst.Count != 0)
        {
            listView1.Items.Remove(lst.First());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future you should show the community the amount of effort you have put into a question. You can tell us what you have tried and give us some examples. However, below is some code that should help answer your question.

```
int id = 0;

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
   if((int)item.Tag == id)
   {
      item.Remove();
      break;
   }
}
```

Note: This assumes that the tag is an integer. If this isn't always the case then you should add code to protect against errors.